# Anaconda navigator and Python unstallation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I uninstall the Anaconda navigator from my window laptop. But still Anaconda3 files show in location which I installed. And still  **Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda3)** / **Anaconda powershell Prompt(Anaconda3)** available when I search using search bar why its still show after the uninstall???

And **again** I installed Anaconda navigator Then I take **Anaconda Prompt(Anaconda3)** but its show following

**Error:** `"The system cannot find the path specified."`

how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: How exactly did you uninstall Conda? We're going to need more information than this.

Comment: I installed it using control panel.

Comment: Did you run anaconda-clean, as mentioned in the [official uninstallation instructions](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/) ?

Comment: Thanks and I refer this document..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the following steps

`1.` execute `conda init` in your command prompt.

`2.` restart the anaconda prompt.

this will initialize the environment again.